# How to run a script as root on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal

What should I type on the Mac OS X terminal to run a script as root?

Comment: I'm a programmer and this question is helping me so I don't think it's off topic.

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It is super-helpful. Upvoted, thank you!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As in any unix-based environment, you can use the [`sudo`](http://xkcd.com/149/) command:

```
$ sudo script-name
```

It will ask for your password (your own, not a separate `root` password).

Answer (score 20):

Or you can access root terminal by typing sudo -s

Answer (score 3):

sudo ./*scriptname*

Answer (score 3):

In order for sudo to work the way everyone suggest, you need to be in the `admin` group.

Answer (score -1):

sudo ./scriptname

sudo bash will basically switch you over to running a shell as root, although it's probably best to stay as su as little as possible.