# Make Install Error, when trying to install Cmake on mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, installation

I am trying to install Cmake on macOS Sierra, and I followed every step here http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/cmake/, but as I get to

```
make install
```

I get this error:

`-- Install configuration: ""
  CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:31 (file):
  file cannot create directory:
  /usr/local/mac-dev-env/cmake-3.9.2/doc/cmake-3.9.  Maybe need
  administrative privileges.`

`make: *** [install] Error 1`

what am I doing wrong?

p.s: I have xcode installed on my system.

Comment: ***what am I doing wrong?*** Although I don't use OSX I believe the error message is correct.

Comment: @drescherjm so do you know how can I give it the administrative privileges?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829/how-to-run-a-script-as-root-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message tells you what you need to do, you need admin privileges. On macOS, that means you need to utilize the `sudo` command.

`sudo make install`

and enter your administrative password at the prompt.

Comment: I do use `sudo make install`, still getting error > ``CMake Error at modules/python3/cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /cv2.  Maybe need administrative privileges.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/cmake_install.cmake:166 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:114 (include)``

Comment: Did you `export MY_INSTALL_DIR` as mentioned in quickstart? Also, I updated cmake_install.cmake file to include MY_INSTALL_DIR location where it was complaining.